# In perl create a multiline String without explicitely concatinating and without \n

Tags: string, perl

I need to write down a complicated MySQL query in perl.
I want to structure it in multiple lines.

Unfortunately,when using EOF notation perl inserts \n into my string.
Is there a way to write down a String in multiple lines, so that perl wont insert \n in it?
I eithr do not want to explicetly concat each line by a +.

Comment: Please show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) as an example. Also, the `+` does not concatenate string in Perl. A `.` does.

Comment: Why do you not want newlines in the statement? MySQL doesn't care either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can easily remove the lines after-the-fact. For example, this:

```
(my $query = <<'EOF') =~ s/\n */ /g;
    SELECT col1,
           MIN(col2)
      FROM t
     WHERE col3 > 17
     GROUP
        BY col1
EOF

print "$query\n";
```

will print this:

```
    SELECT col1, MIN(col2) FROM table t WHERE col3 > 17 GROUP BY col1
```

---

**Edited to add:**

A few things to note about the above:

- It's O.K. to wrap a `my`-expression in parentheses; the variable is still scoped to the enclosing block.
- A `my`-expression evaluates to the variable that it declares, and you can continue to modify that variable. For example:

  ```
  (my $three) = 3;                        # same as:  my $three = 3;
  (my $four = 2) += 2;                    # same as:  my $four = 4;
  (my $five = 'twenty-five') =~ s/.*-//;  # same as:  my $five = 'five';
  ```
- The heredoc notation `<<` starts the heredoc (the multiline string) on the *following* line. For example:

  ```
  my $abc = <<'EOF' . 'xyz';    # same as:  my $abc = "abc\nxyz";
  abc
  EOF
  ```

  In fact, this is actually very common; it's slightly unusual for `<<EOF` to be the *very* last thing on the line, because if nothing else, there's usually a semicolon after it to indicate the end of the statement.

  If you have multiple heredocs on the same line, then each one starts on the line after the previous one ends:

  ```
  my $abc = <<'EOF1' . <<'EOF2';    # same as:  my $abc = "abc\nxyz\n";
  abc
  EOF1
  xyz
  EOF2
  ```

Comment: Yeah, thnx that will work, but I thought that there should be a solution which wont force me explicitely remove the newlines.

Comment: Can you tell me, where I can find more about this syntax, where the regexp replace comes after  EOF?

Comment: See the documentation of here-documents at in the [Perl operator documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators). Basically, it returns everything starting from the _next_ line until `EOF`; the rest of the current line is processed normally.

Comment: @Skip: I've updated my answer to explain some points of potential confusion. There's no specific regexp-replace-after-EOF syntax; it's just the result of various bits of normal syntax coming together.